# SSRS dynamic expression based on Parameter

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I had an expression that looked like this:

```
=Sum(Fields!MO1.Value, "DataSet_Eligibility") + 
Sum(Fields!MO2.Value, "DataSet_Eligibility") + 
Sum(Fields!MO3.Value, "DataSet_Eligibility") +
Sum(Fields!MO4.Value, "DataSet_Eligibility") +
Sum(Fields!MO5.Value, "DataSet_Eligibility") +
Sum(Fields!MO6.Value, "DataSet_Eligibility")
```

Which worked great.

Then I added parameters that let the user choose date ranges so it could be 3 months or could be 24 months (or more). My dynamic query creates the number of fields based on however many months (3 months = 3 fields, 24 months = 24 fields).

Is there a way to dynamically create the formula above based on the number of months?

I can calculate how many months there are, but I can't figure out how to create the formula that only sums the number of months/fields that I have.

Comment: In your dynamic query, why not add an extra column that is the sum of all the created fields?  Then the above expression could just point to that field in the dataset.

Comment: That's a good idea. I didn't consider that. That might be the way I go. I'll give it a shot and see how ti goes.

Comment: I tried this but forgot that each dynamic field is a sub-query, which I can't do aggregates on.

Comment: It sounds like the dataset isn't meeting the requirement of the report.  Which usually means that it needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Can't you UNPIVOT the data and let an SSRS Matrix generate the months as needed? Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247751/dynamic-columns-sql-server-months-as-columns

Comment: Ooo, that looks interesting. I've never used UNPIVOT. It might take me a bit to figure out how to get it to work, but it looks like it might do the job.
Thanks for the link!